# Click Trigger option not available in Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to add click tracking via Google Tag Manager. I've been watching [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ghUwerH1fsw) but what I'm seeing is different than what's visible in the tutorial.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0X7q.png)

Specifically, the ability to add Clicks is not available. I'm not sure if it's a permissions thing but I'm the admin of my GTM account, and the app is hooked up and receiving data through Google Analytics.

I tried going through my account settings and looking for anywhere I could turn on click tracking, but couldn't find anything. I expect click triggers to simply be available as an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you created a server-side container rather than web container.

If you want to follow the tutorial. Please create a web container again.